# neo4j: node jumps when clicked on

Tags: neo4j, properties, nodes

i've a node with lots of properties.
normally, when i click a node, all properties will be shown below.

but with this node, there are so many properties that, when clicked on, the window gets widened and the node (with all its relations) get centered, so its jumps to the right away from my mouse. 
then the mouse is no longer on the node, the properties dont need to be shown and the node jump back. then its on the mouse again, and yes it jumps away again such that the properties fit below. sigh.

In this way, I can only click the node when I scroll out (and all properties fit below). But then my nodes are very small and I cant read the properties.

please help!

[Before clicking on the blue node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIgTZ.png)
[After clinking on the blue node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD4F5.png)
Notice the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the image

Comment: Please clarify your question adding some screenshots of the issues you're encountering.

Comment: Yes, see screenshots in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by internet explorer. If you use Chrome, this problem does not occur.